# In Arcobjects, what is the difference between feature.shape and feature.ShapeCopy?

Tags: arcobjects

What is the difference between `Feature.shape` and `Feature.ShapeCopy` in ArcObjects. I am using `Feature.shape` could you please tell me difference?

Answer (score 2):

From the ArcObjects documentation available [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000331000000).

> The ShapeCopy property is a cloned copy of the feature’s Shape. When modifying the geometry of a feature or a set of features, use the ShapeCopy property to obtain a copy of the feature's geometry, perform the modification on the geometries, then apply the modifications by setting the geometry to the Shape property.